# VBA - Count Values Based on Multiple Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am new in here so I still have many things to learn. Besides, I am not a native English-speaker, so it will be difficult for me to explain things. Anyways, I will try my best.

I am having issue with counting values based on multiple criteria. For example, I have two criteria which are "A" and "B". However, I only get the last value in each row. I have already used COUNTIFS but it still doesn't work.

Please take a look as below for better understanding of what I am doing.

```
Criteria |  C  |  D  |  E  |         Criteria |  C  |  D  |  E  |
   A     |  x  |     |  x  |             A    |  1  |     |  1  |
   B     |     |     |  x  |  -->        B    |     |     |  1  |
   A     |  x  |     |     |
```

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
Sub Run_Report()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim EndRow As Long
EndRow = wb.Sheets("MDR").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row

wb.Sheets("Report").Range("E9:N17").ClearContents

Dim LastCol As Long

For i = 9 To EndRow
    LastCol = wb.Sheets("MDR").Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    If LastCol > 5 And LastCol < 15 And wb.Sheets("MDR").Cells(i, LastCol).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
         sht.Cells(9, wb.Sheets("MDR").Cells(i, LastCol).column).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wb.Sheets("MDR").Range("D9:D" & EndRow), "General", _
         wb.Sheets("MDR").Range("A9:N" & EndRow).Columns(wb.Sheets("MDR").Cells(i, LastCol).column), "<>" & "")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the example data you supplied what you are **getting** or what you **want**?  (If it is what you want, it doesn't sound like you want to count anything - you just want to see if a condition is met anywhere.  [Which I guess could be done by testing whether the count > 0, so perhaps a count is appropriate.])

Comment: FWIW - everywhere where you have `wb.Sheets("MDR").Cells(i, LastCol).column` in your code, you can replace it with `LastCol`.  The two terms are identical.

Comment: The left data is what I get and the right one is the output that I want to make. For example. in row A, I have two value in C & E, but I only need to get **last value**, so I will take the one in column E and that count 1. Besides, in third row, it also has same criteria which is A, but it only has one value in column C, so that counts 1. And same as row B.